# How to check other available metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

We are making API call to https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet

Below are the Metrics Data which we are receiving from Google Analytics API. Can someone help me in understanding what all other metrics we have and how to check that?

- "ga:transactions"
- "ga:sessions"
- "ga:transactionRevenue"
- "ga:itemQuantity"
  "ga:users"

Thanks,
pavan..

Comment: Not sure i understand the question but this is a list of all the diemsnions and metrics you can use with the google analytics api https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

The Dimensions & Metrics Explorer lists and describes all of the dimensions and metrics available through the Core Reporting API.

The Dimensions & Metrics Explorer has the following features:

**Explore all of the dimensions and metrics** – Search or browse by group. Select a dimension or metric for additional details such as descriptions and attributes.

**Identify valid combinations** – Not all dimensions and metrics can be queried together. Only certain dimensions and metrics can be used together to create valid combinations. Select a dimension or metric checkbox to see all the other values that can be combined in the same query.

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/